# gnuplot all points y value undefined

Tags: gnuplot, undefined

I just dont get it. What I am doing wrong.
This data file:
test.csv

```
1981-12-12-12:12:12,12
1981-12-12-13:12:12,15
1981-12-12-14:12:12,18
```

And this gnuplot script:

```
set datafile separator ','
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'
set xrange ["1981-12-12-12:12:12":"1981-12-12-14:12:12"]
plot 'test.csv' using 0:1 with lines
```

Error:

```
plot 'test.csv' using 0:1 with lines
                                    ^
"kuehl.plot", line 5: all points y value undefined!
```

Gnuplot Version 5.2 patchlevel 2 (Gentoo revision r0)

Comment: `plot ... using 1:2`

Comment: Damn, you*re right! I had so much counting from 0 in my last projects that I assumed gnuplot would also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot start counting columns at `1`, so you must use

```
plot 'test.csv' using 1:2 with lines
```

BTW: column `0` isn't an error because it gives you the current row number. So it only gives you the wrong range.